# SVD - Compute only x number of eigenvector of matrix U

Tags: matlab, matrix, svd, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have an m by n matrix input from an image which eventually converted into a vector matrix with N-data set. For example, an image with 40x40 size will become 400x1 matrix data. So, if I have 50 images, the input will become 400x50 data matrix.

The SVD will produce three matrices as the result of decomposition :

U mxm, S mxn, V nxn.

With the same size input it will become :

U (400x400) size , S (400x50) size, and V (50x50).

Since the overall computation takes too long and I only need about 50 eigenvectors of matrix U, how can I stop the process and get the output of matrix U (400x50) size instead of U (400x400) size?

I'm using the jacobi method, here's the code :

```
while (sum(abs(A(~eye(m,n)))) > e)
  for i = 1:n
      for j = i+1:n
          [J1,J2] = jacobi1(A,m,n,i,j);
          A = mtimes(J1,mtimes(A,J2));
          U = mtimes(U,J1');
          V = mtimes(J2',V);
      end
      for j = n+1:m
          J1 = jacobi2(A,m,n,i,j);
          A = mtimes(J1,A);
          U = mtimes(U,J1');
      end
    %  progressbar((i/10)/pb);
  end
 end
```

Comment: Why don't you use svd method directly which is a way faster than that ? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html#bu2_4r8

Comment: Well, it's for research and implementation ...

Comment: @ted7 If you do it manually you need to be careful of numerical precision issues. I'd go with Matlab's `svd`

Comment: I know ... I just need to turn off the whole computations after I gained the number of eigenvector that I need, even though the computation of matrix S and V hasn't finished yet. I only use the eigenvector afterward anyway ... I'm having trouble to check whether the column is ready or not ...